# Reflexive reduct of preorder

Tags: model-theory

Suppose P is a preorder on a set S, a reflexive and transitive relation. Suppose we subtract from P the identity relation and get a relation Q on S. Is the class of all such relations a first-order axiomatizable class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

1. $\neg r(x,x)$
2. $r(x,y)\vee x=y$ is transitive.